# program doesn't not work on windows services

Tags: windows, service, go

i made this test program test.exe

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "time"
)
func main(){
        for{
                fmt.Println("hello")
                time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        }
}
```

i wanna register this file with background at windows services (services.msc)

i tried that all command sc, nssm, srvany like this

```
sc create TestService binpath=C:\User\sds\Desktop\test.exe
nssm install TestService C:\User\sds\Desktop\test.exe
```

service registration is success in services but it is not work going to be stoped with 1053 error message

i wanna run this program at windows background service

plz

Comment: Do it properly with the `svc` package? - Where do you expect to see output? Services are isolated so you would not see/be able to interact with anything. (FYI 1053 is a startup timeout error)

Comment: i didn't use svc package bc svc package is hard for me