# Launch a server executable on a port in windows using golang

Tags: windows, go, service, server

I am trying to launch multiple servers on different ports on my windows machine using golang. This is for an internal testing purpose.

So the end result is to have an executable which will launch multiple instances of my server(another windows executable) on multiple ports. My ideal approach would be to have "n" go routines that launch the command "myserver.exe .\config.json port+n" on ports ranging from "port+0" to "port+n" so that I would have "n" servers up and running. I am figuring out a way to launch my server and keep listening until I want the program to end.

I have my server as an windows executable which serves on a port mentioned while launching it. It works fine when I launch it manually. It can be launched as :

```
C:\Install\myServer.exe C:\Install\Configuration.json 8079
```

The above command starts the server and listens to the port 8079. I would like to launch multiple instances of the same server on different ports. The code that I have written following [golang program doesn't not work on windows services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040234/golang-program-doesnt-not-work-on-windows-services) and https://github.com/kardianos/service is below. I can see that the command to start my server has been executed but I donot see any services when I open the services.msc neither when I do a get-service powershell command. I also tried to see if I can listen to the port 8079(in this case) after launching through my go program to see if I get any response but I get the following error:

```
panic: Get http://localhost:8079/config: dial tcp [::1]:8079: connectex: No connection could be made because the targetmachine actively refused it.
```

Following is the code:

```
var logger service.Logger

type program struct{}

func (p *program) Start(s service.Service) error {
    // Start should not block. Do the actual work async.
    go p.run()
    return nil
}
func (p *program) run() {
    /*// Do work here
    // the following sleep-print was used for testing if this method is actually being executed and it worked. 
    fmt.Println("Waiting")
    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("waited")
    */
    command := "C:\\Install\\myServer.exe C:\\Install\\Configuration.json "+ flag.Arg(0) 
    fmt.Println("Creating the command", command)
    c := exec.Command("cmd", command )

    var outb, errb bytes.Buffer
    c.Stdout = &outb
    c.Stderr = &errb

    fmt.Println("Starting the command")
    if err := c.Run(); err != nil { 
        fmt.Println("Error: ", err)
    }else{
        fmt.Println("out:", outb.String(), "err:", errb.String())
    }
    fmt.Println("After run issued")
    //
}
func (p *program) Stop(s service.Service) error {
    // Stop should not block. Return with a few seconds.
    return nil
}

func main() {
    flag.Parse() // get the source and destination directory

    svcConfig := &service.Config{
        Name:        "GoServiceExampleSimple",
        DisplayName: "Go Service Example",
        Description: "This is an example Go service.",
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v+", svcConfig)

    prg := &program{}
    s, err := service.New(prg, svcConfig)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    logger, err = s.Logger(nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("Main Run")
    err = s.Run()
    fmt.Println("After Main Run")
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(err)
    }
}
```

Output of the above code:

```
Main Run
Creating the command C:\Install\myServer.exe C:\Install\Configuration.json 8079
Starting the command
out: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.3.9600]
(c) 2013 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to use the /c to the command in order to execute the command in bash in windows. Without the the command was not being executed.

```
command := []string{"/c", "C:\\Install\\Build\\server.exe start " }
out, err := ExecuteCommandInWindows(command, "run")
if err != "" {
    fmt.Println(err, len(err))
}else{
    fmt.Println(out)
}
```